# Github Actions variable showing output as null

Tags: bash, github, environment-variables, github-actions, workflow

This is a step in my workflow:

```
- name: Fetching INT creds
  if: ${{ github.event.inputs.resourcesCreated == 'true' }}
  id: int-creds
  run: |
    az login --service-principal -u X -p Y --tenant Z
    INTEGRATION=$(az identity show --name int-${{ steps.service-id-valid.outputs.service-id-valid }} --resource-group XxX --query 'clientId' -otsv)
    echo "::set-output name=int-creds-valid::${INTEGRATION}"
    echo "${{ steps.int-creds.outputs.int-creds-valid }}"
```

I've added the last echo command in order to see the output (for checking purposes).
However I allways receive it as null.
When I echo $INTEGRATION, I will see the requested output.
Any idea why the set-output command seems to not work ?

I spent a few hours looking for a work around but couldn't find it, thanks.

Comment: I doubt that the output is available in the same step you created it. Can you please try and add a new run step and show the output there?

Comment: You are acctually correct..
It's not possible to show output from within the same step, thanks.